# How to define a model & method in mongoose midleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a newbie in mongodb and nodejs. I create a schema such as :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
   name : String,
   email: String,
   number : String
});

ContactSchema.methods.selectAll = function (callback){
    console.log("I got list contact");

    ContactModel.find({}).exec(function(err,items){
        if(err)
            console.error(err.stack);
        else{
            var notify = {
                'message' : 'select all document successfully',
                'data' : items,
                'status' : 1
            };

            console.log(notify);
            callback();
        };
    });
};

var ContactModel = mongoose.model('contactlist',ContactSchema);

module.exports = ContactModel;
```

Assume that I have connected to database with `'mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist'`. It has a database name `contactlist`, a collection `contactlist` with some documents

```
> db.contactlist.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576e8ac6d68807e6244f3cdb"), "name" : "Tome", "email" : "Tome@gmail.com", "number" : "333-333-333" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576e8b4fd68807e6244f3cdc"), "name" : "Trace", "email" : "Trace@gmail.com", "number" : "444-444-444" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("576e8b4fd68807e6244f3cdd"), "name" : "Tuker", "email" : "Tuker@gmail.com", "number" : "555-444-777" }
>
```

**My Question**:

1. *What does exactly `'ContactModel'` in `mongoose.model('ContactModel',ContactSchema);` stand for?* *It is a name self-define or exactly name of collection in db?*

   2. I want to create a method for model ( crud task )

   `ContactSchema.methods.selectAll = function (){
      // code here
   }`

This method can select all documents of a collection in mongo but my `ContactModel.find` function return null items.

```
$ node server
development server is running at 127.0.0.1 port 3000
I got list contact
{ message: 'select all document successfully',
data: [],
status: 1 }
undefined
```

I mean when I use `find` api  of mongoose. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you already had solved your problem somehow. But this is just to address the root cause of problem the problem you faced. Hoping other find it helpful.

I think you have created a database named `contactlist` and a collection named `contactlist` before mongoose did it. And mongoose tries to be smart and puts the collection name as the name of model's pluralize (lib/npm source code [reference](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L31) and all the relevant rules are defined in [this file](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/utils.js)). In your case it might have created a collection named `contactlists`

Although there is options for you to explicitly name your collection when creating a model by passing it as the third parameter to model (the way you did it) :

```
var ContactSchema = new Schema({ name : String /* , .....  */ },{collection : 'contactlist'});
```

---

This behavior is clearly documented in mongoose model [API reference](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model):

> When no collection argument is passed, Mongoose produces a collection name by passing the model name to the utils.toCollectionName method. This method pluralizes the name. If you don't like this behavior, either pass a collection name or set your schemas collection name option.

Answer (score 0):

I resloved my problem. We have to map us with collection by

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
   name : String,
   email: String,
   number : String
},{collection : 'contactlist'});
```

I worked!